# Electron window focus

Tags: javascript, electron

In my Electron app, I have a new Browser window that is opened as a sort of "notification" to the user that something happened in my (unfocused) app.

This new window has a button to "ignore" the notification.

The problem is that when they click ignore, the main Browser window comes into focus, even though the code merely closes the window.

Is there a way to make it so that interacting with a new Browser window doesn't also focus the main Browser window?

This is how I am spawning the window:

```
    messageWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width,
        height,
        y: top,
        x: left,
        alwaysOnTop: true,
        closable: true,
        minimizable: false,
        resizable: false,
        show: false,
        title: 'Message Notification',
        frame: false,
        hasShadow: false,
        acceptFirstMouse: true,
    });

    messageWindow.loadURL(
        url.format({
            pathname: path.join(app.getAppPath(),'./foo.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true,
        })
    );

    messageWindow.on('closed', () => {
        messageWindow = null;
    });

    messageWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        messageWindow.show();
    });
```

Then I react to the "ignore" button being clicked like this:

```
ipcMain.on('message-notification-hide', (event, data) => {
    if (messageWindow) messageWindow.close();
});
```

All of this code works, but the focus returns to the main window.

Comment: On which OS do you see this behavior?

Comment: @shashi I am on OSX